# Prolific USB driver on OSX 10.13

Tags: macos, usb, usbserial

[image]I'm trying to use the prolific USB driver on OSX 10.13, I've run the installer but can't get the computer to see the device. From the PDF it references USB Controller D, I don't have that, I've attached the screen shot.

I can't even pass the device to a virtual machine to use there.[image]

Comment: Was the device plugged in when that screenshot was taken? The device should show up in that list even if the driver isn’t installed/working right.

Comment: @BrendanShanks it wasn't at that point, I've uploaded a screen shot with it.